# Word 2010 Number of pages without first page

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers

I show the number of pages as 1 / 4, with 4 being the total number of pages. But I do not want to count the first page.

Important: I know how to do it for the current page number (Starting at ..), I mean the **total number of pages.**

So if the document has one cover page + 3 pages, I want to show it as 1/3, 2/3 ..., not as 1/4.

Comment: not really, it mainly explains how to start again with 1, but does not reflect the total number of pages

Comment: Again referring to current number of page, not total number of pages. Answer below. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This question has a superior answer to the linked "Word 2007 not counting first pages" which has a link-only answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use a formula:

```
{ = { NUMPAGES } - 1 }
```

Purists can even write ([Examples](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-numpages-field-HA102017464.aspx)) as below and use StartingNumber

```
Page { PAGE } of { = (StartingNumber - 1) + { NUMPAGES } }
```

In order to [avoid the syntax error](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/why-do-get-syntax-error-try-enter-numpages-1-a-t2785006.html):

> I would say that you are typing litterally the "{NumPages}" part. You
>   need to use CTRL+F9 to enter the both field brace pairs { { } } and
>   then type in the text { = { NumPages } - 1 }
>   Then you need to press F9 after you enter it to make it active.

Comment: That last part helped a lot. I was trying to figure out why mine wasn't working properly.

Comment: When I used `{ = { NUMPAGES } - 1 }` in above approach CTRL+F9, the code result returns **!Invalid Character Setting**.

Comment: I finally understood that for these formulas - as Horst Walter is saying - NEVER type a curly bracket! Always push Cntr-F9, which adds the special brackets. For complete dum-heads like me: put cursor where you want the field, Cntr-F9, type "=", Cntr-F9, type "NUMPAGES", move outside inner bracket, type " - 1", press F9.

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way to do it, if you don't use sections in your document:

- Put your content in a different section than the title page. That is, add a section break between them:

[image]

- Add the number of pages in section (SectionPages field) to your footnote:

  [image]